# How to use multiple scenarios in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have to test ramping up 1 user every minute for 10 minutes and then then ramping up 20 users ever minutes for next 10 minutes with jmeter. I tried to search on internet, seems like I need to use ultimate thread? If so can someone please give me an example of above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple regular thread groups and in Test Plan,you can select Run thread Group consecutively.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ultimate Thread plugin allows fine grained control of user threads. It will certainly achieve the concurrency pattern you're looking for. You can also start a thread group delayed with just out-of-the-box Jmeter though:

Use 2 thread groups, and set the required ramp up rates for each thread group. Since you need the second thread group to kick in 10 minutes after the test starts, add a startup delay of 600 seconds.

[image]

The relevant jmeter documentation is in [Section 4.1 here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html):

> Version 1.9 introduces a test run scheduler. Click the checkbox at the bottom of the Thread Group panel to reveal extra fields in which you can enter the start and end times of the run. When the test is started, JMeter will wait if necessary until the start-time has been reached. At the end of each cycle, JMeter checks if the end-time has been reached, and if so, the run is stopped, otherwise the test is allowed to continue until the iteration limit is reached.
>
> Alternatively, one can use the relative delay and duration fields. Note that delay overrides start-time, and duration over-rides end-time.

Comment: so do i need to multiple thread groups and each thread group should contain the script and work individually.Does not Ultimate thread looks like a better approach.if so can u give me an example with above scenario plz.For the above scenario you have given do i need to add ramp up time 600 for threads to execute 10 jusers ,so every min one user will be ramped up

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do with 1 ultimate thread group.

Your setup should be as given below. You did not mention the test duration. I assumed it as 3600 seconds.

- 1st Row : We will have 10 threads in 600 seconds by starting a thread every min.
- 2nd Row: We will have additional 200 threads (ignoring the first 10 threads), in the next 600 seconds by starting 20 threads every 1 min.

We need a wait for 600 seconds in the second row which is update in `Initial Delay` field for the first row to complete.

[image]

Comment: so does that mean it will execute 210 users in an hour but why it is showing total time to execute in graph as 1:10 hours

Comment: I say that to hold for 1 hr once we have reached 10 users. that is why it will run for 1 hr 10 mins. You can adjust it as you want!

Comment: but when i execute test,it does not wait 60 seconds to ramp up,it keeps on executing the transaction.DO i need do something else as well.In summary report it is showing that thread is continuously running

Comment: @jassar, as soon as a thread is started, it will start executing the samplers.  What is the issue here?

Comment: i think it is the time as we put 3600seconds time,seems like it is executing 5 threads as defined in the above example by you,it is executing 5 threads for an hour.it is keep on executing thread one with user1 for multiple times and i only want to execute thread1 user1 once and then user2

Comment: @jassar, why do you want to do only once? :( .. How do you simulate that concurrent 200 users load if an user executes the sampler only once? for ex: i assume you want to execute a task & it takes 1 second to execute. first second jmeter creates an user which executes the task. Jmeter waits for 10 seconds to create another user. By the time, first user would have finishted its task. So, after 10 seconds, JMeter create another user. Now - you have only one active user as the first user is not active any more. So, in this way - you can not simulate 200 users load.

Comment: Vinoth,it takes about 15 seconds for one user action,but as per our configuration it should wait for 60 seconds to create another user as we have mentioned start up time 600 seconds for 10 users but it does not wait for 60 seconds and keep on executing transactions.

Comment: @jassar, if you want an user to do those actions only once, use the regular Thread Group. There you can mention - how many loops an user should do. This ultimate thread group is time driven. If you mention 1 hr, these users will repeat the same actions again and again for 1 hr - as i said - after 15 seconds, you will lose an user. So you can not maintain 200 users load.

Comment: so for the above scenario do i need to use regular thread group twice?

Comment: for the second senario,it is saying 20 users every minute for 10 minutes,if i give ramp ramp up time time for threads 200 and ramp up 600.it will execute every user every 3 seconds.but as per scenario it has to be 20 users every minute.